# How can I count of duplicated data in Microsoft List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, microsoft-lists

I have the below data in Microsoft List, I need count of repeated IDs.

```
Emp ID  SERIAL_NO       MAKE        Emp Id repeated Count
Emp1    FVFH36FZQ05N    APPLE MAC
Emp2    PW039DX5        LENOVO
Emp2    PF42AHJ9        LENOVO
Emp3    PF42AHHF        LENOVO
Emp1    TWR29P1W2G      APPLE MAC
Emp3    PW039DL5        LENOVO
Emp2    PW039DLZ        LENOVO
Emp4    PF42CSRB        LENOVO
Emp4    PW039DPJ        LENOVO
Emp5    R90BAX5L        LENOVO
Emp5    R90BAX5H        LENOVO
```

Comment: Hi, did you try below solution? Is it working for you or you still need any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution to check the count of duplicate Employee IDs will be - add grouping on the "Emp ID" column:

Group by Emp ID like this:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use grouping to modify a list or library view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-grouping-to-modify-a-list-or-library-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7)

Comment: I'm checking the progress of this issue. Did Ganesh Sanap 's answer help you?